# NICE a process and set it to RT

Tags: linux, fedora, nice

I have a Fedora system with sopcast running two streams. When I watch the stream locally it looks perfectly. But after being processed through my Fedora-box its a bit choppy. I want to set the streams to realtime and prioritize it over everything.

As you can see below I've tried setting it to NICE -20 and the other consuming processes to something higher. It seems like it got worse after.

How do I make it realtime? Could it be better after setting it for RT? The user running my streams is operate. And everything running on my init 5 + root should be prioritized lowest.

```
top - 02:09:54 up  1:25,  3 users,  load average: 0.11, 0.10, 0.09
Tasks: 185 total,   2 running, 183 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.3%us,  0.9%sy,  1.2%ni, 96.7%id,  0.4%wa,  0.2%hi,  0.2%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   5914932k total,  2456904k used,  3458028k free,    68296k buffers
Swap:  8028156k total,        0k used,  8028156k free,  1557048k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND            
 3775 deluge    39  19  572m  42m  10m S  3.0  0.7   0:50.89 deluged            
 1826 root      20   0  148m  20m 8544 S  1.0  0.4   0:21.69 Xorg               
 2436 administ  25   5  225m 2520 1764 S  1.0  0.0   0:07.44 synergyc           
 1716 operate    0 -20 19596 8244 1884 S  0.7  0.1   0:40.56 sp-so-auth         
 2367 administ  25   5  572m  15m 9.8m S  0.7  0.3   0:04.47 gnome-terminal     
   24 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.3  0.0   0:00.24 migration/3        
  824 deluge    39  19  245m  30m 4236 S  0.3  0.5   0:16.45 deluge
```

Any other sugestions for getting the stream better? Doesn't seem like the processor is struggling processing it, but still. Deluge seems like it takes quite a lot. That one should be NICED positive?

Edit:
As a sidenote. My internet-connection is not maxing out. I'm running a BW monitor on the router (DD-WRT). And it shows a upload average of 2Mbit out of 10 Mbit and an average of 0,4 download out of 100Mbit. But the graph itself is behaving really strange. See attached picture. I've been wondering what this could be. Also talked with my provider about MTU and such, but they told everything looked good. As you can see, it's acting strange kind of falling down every other second. Almost as if it hits an maximum window-sizing somewhere. The streams are RTP / HTTP based and is in total 350Kbits + 20Kbits sound.

[image: Bandwidth monitor graph]

Answer (score 2):

Your system is almost completely (96.7%) idle. Changing CPU priorities will not affect anything, because every process on your system is already getting all the CPU time it needs.

Given that you are running deluge, you may be starved for bandwidth. Stop any torrents you have running, or cap their bandwidth usage to a reasonable level.

Comment: Actually not running any torrent at all. Just have the deamon running since it wont stay dead after killing it. + I use it ocationally together with flexget. Could there be anything else i havent thought about? Sloppy internet connection maye?

Comment: As a sidenoete. Im running a BW monitor on the route (DD-WRT). And it shows a upload average at 2Mbit out of 10 Mbit and an average of 0,4 download out of 100Mbit. But the graph itself is behaving really strange. Ill upload a picture in my original post so you can see. Ive been wondering what this could be. Also talked with my provider about MTU and such, but they told everything looked good. See the picture above.

Comment: The bandwidth bottleneck could be _way_ upstream from your ISP...